# Five equal classes and relative frequency

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, numerical-methods

Make the following numeric data into five equal classes and find the relative frequency of each one class

$4.4,8.1,15.3,23.4,5.5,7.2,1.3,7.3,18.1,4.8,6.1,12.3,16.3,8.4,24.0,3.9,15.4$

Any ideas how to approach this statistic math problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is order from least to greatest. Then to find the class width you do $CW= \frac{max - min}{5}$ (round). Then start at minimum value for your first class and add the class width.

i.e
$cw= 10 
\\2-11 
\\12-21$